# How to unit test @Secured in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, junit4

Basically I was trying to unit test on `@Secured` feature in my application. Below is the code snippet on the secure implementation:

```
@Service
public class ReportService {

    @Secured(value={"ROLE_EMPLOYEE_A"})
    public void funcA() {
        System.out.println("This only accessible for Employee A.");
    }

}
```

Now I have a series of `Employee` users define in Spring Security just for my unit test purpose:

```
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:password-encoder hash="plaintext"/>
        <security:user-service>
           <security:user name="empl1" password="pass1" authorities="ROLE_EMPLOYEE_A" />
           <security:user name="empl2" password="pass2" authorities="ROLE_EMPLOYEE_B" />
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
 </security:authentication-manager>
```

In my unit test code, I have the following being define:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
"classpath:applicationcontext.xml",
"classpath:securitycontext.xml"
})
public class ReportServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private ReportService reportService;

    @Test(expected = AccessDeniedException.class)
    public void testA() {
        assertNotNull(userService);

        UserDetails ud = userService.loadUserByUsername("empl2");
        assertNotNull(ud);

        Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(ud.getUsername(), ud.getPassword(), ud.getAuthorities());
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        reportService.funcA();
}
```

In this test, I am expecting `AccessDeniedException` being thrown, but somehow the test were pass and "*This only accessible for Employee A.*" were printed in console output. I'm sure the real execution is working fine, but I'm so curious to know why it doesn't work in unit test?

Comment: Your `empl1` has `ROLE_EMPLOYEE_A`. Why it should fail?

Comment: Sorry, there is my typo error, I have amend it to `empl2`. I'm loading user `empl2` in my test code, not user `empl1`. Sorry for my mistake.